# SQL Server 2008 R2: Show the dates day into comma separated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with two fields:

```
create table test_t
(
cola varchar(10),
coldate date
);
```

Inserting some records:

```
insert into test_t values('A','1-1-2010'),
                         ('A','2-1-2010'),
                         ('A','4-1-2010'),
                         ('B','6-1-2010'),
                         ('B','8-1-2010'),
                         ('C','10-1-2010'),
                         ('D','11-1-2010');
```

**Note**: Now I want to show the `cola` values which are belongs to 2 to 3 days. And want 
to show that dates day into comma separated column as shown below in the expected
ouptput.

**Expected Output**:

```
cola    Dates_Day
------------------
A       1,2,4
B       6,8
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: @Paresh J, Nope! This is with different condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select t1.cola, stuff((SELECT ',' + right(convert(varchar(5),t2.coldate,3),2)  from
test_t t2 where t2.cola = t1.cola FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Dates_Day 
from test_t  t1
group by t1.cola
```

Comment: How to avoid the prefix 0 in single digit dates??.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09779/1

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to remove prefix 0 for single digit

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
COLA,
STUFF ((SELECT   ','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,RIGHT(LEFT(COLDATE,7),2)) FROM TEST_T B WHERE A.COLA = B.COLA FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [Dates_Day]
FROM TEST_T A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select COLA, 
   listagg(TO_CHAR(COLDATE,'DD'),',') within group (order by COLDATE) AS CDAY
    from TEST_T
    group by COLA;
```